# Funcion para crear y activar venv con python

Tags: python, virtualenv

Estoy intentando crear una función donde te crea y te activa un ambiente virtual. El problema es que al finalizar el programa solo se crea la carpeta venv pero no se activa. Adjunto código que he intentado:

```
def create_venv(_dir):
    os.system("py -m venv venv")
    os.chdir(".\\venv\\Scripts\\")
    os.startfile("activate.bat")

def create_venv(_dir):
    os.system("py -m venv venv")
    os.system(".\\venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat")
```

¿Hay alguna forma de que se quede activado después de que finalice el programa?

Comment: Hasta dónde entiendo no se puede manipular la variables de entorno del proceso "caller" del script, por eso los entornos virtuales tienen scripts de linea de comando que lo hace, el clásico activate.

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado!**
Para poder activar y que se quede activado el entorno virtual después de que finalice el programa solo hay que modificar `activate.bat` añadiéndole al final `cmd /k`

```
def create_venv(_dir):
    os.system("py -m venv venv")
    activate_path  = _dir + "\\venv\\Scripts"
    os.chdir(activate_path)
    os.system("echo cmd /k >> activate.bat")
    os.system("activate.bat")
```

Comment: Con el `cmd /k` estas abriendo una nueva terminal y si a esta nueva terminal puedes modificarle las variables de entorno, pero por debajo sigues teniendo python y el cmd original.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho veo que añadiendo solo `cmd` al final del archivo .bat también funciona, ¿Qué diferencia hay entre poner `/k` y no ponerlo?

Comment: Según: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd el `cmd /k comando` ejecuta el comando y continua dejandote una terminal o sesión nueva abierta, si no lo pones, solo abre el `cmd` sin ejecutar nada